# How does ViewBinding generate code in real time？

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

When i use ViewBinding, it always generate `xxxxxBinding`.

I know android use `Android Gradle Plugin` build apk with code and resources。

And they're going to split some task (or transform).

I know task(transform) will build some file into `./build` .

But the ViewBinding makes me confused，He doesn't appear to be generating files（Because every time I create layout file, I can access it directly）(Or I can just delete the build folder and it won't be created again，But he can still get it right（No error） in the code)。

Were some files secretly generated?

If so, where will it be generated?

If not, how can I do the same? For example, use a markdown file to generate code in real time.

Comment: as you said xxxxxBinding will be created. There will be atleast 2 build folder for each android project. Did you delete the build folder in the root directory or inside app directory( here app is a module directory)?. For every build, xxxxxBinding will be generated

Comment: There's new thing in Gradle called incremental processing & ViewBinding processes uses the same to generate files on the go. So whenever any layout file changes, it gets reflected to generate Binding class.

Comment: @VaikundamRaghul I delete the build folder inside app directory. 
`/app/build/`

@JeelVankhede So, where can i spot this `Binding class`? Are them in some file  ?

Comment: Generally Binding class can be found in `app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out/com/example/package/databinding`. Here `com/example/package` refers to the package name `com.example.package`. Let me know if it is there

Comment: @VaikundamRaghul I know there will generated Binding class, 
But when i delete that folder, I still can visit new layout's Binding class while there is no one build folder.

Comment: I know my expression must have been inaccurate. I'm very, very sorry

Comment: I now realize that my problem is actually that `R.laayout.xxx` can still be written in code without error even if the build folder is not there.